# Getting the last String token with Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I implement a String tokenizer and get the last token of a String separated with comma `","` using javascript?

The String to be tokenized may get very large, and that it needs to be memory efficient so the browser won't hang.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String split and get first and last occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497264/string-split-and-get-first-and-last-occurrences)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can probably split the string on the separator and then reference the last item in the resulting array:

```js
var tokenstring = "token1,token2,token3,token4",
    arr = tokenstring.split( ',' ),
    lastToken = arr.pop();  // .pop() removes and returns the last item of the array

console.log( lastToken );
```

Comment: Much better than mine. Did not know about that function, nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
function reverse(s){
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}

function getLast(s)
{
  var reversed = reverse(s);
  return reverse(reversed.substring(0, reversed.indexOf(',')));
}
```