# String split and get first and last occurrences

Tags: javascript

I have a long string of ISO dates:

```
var str = "'2012-11-10T00:00:00.000Z', '2012-11-11T00:00:00.000Z', ****  '2013-11-12T00:00:00.000Z'";
```

I need to get the first and last dates only. I could do

```
var vStr = str.split(',');
vStr[0] and vStr[vStr.length - 1]
```

But it's a waste memory, because I only need the first and last occurrences. Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Why would it be a waste of memory, seems like a good enough way to do it, but you could just use `shift()` and `pop()` to get the first and last from the array. This probably uses 0.00000000000000000001% of the memory on a clients computer, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: it'd be `vStr[vStr.length - 1]`

Comment: Your string is hardly "long" so it wouldn't take very much memory at all...

Comment: If you are concerned about memory (not that it's an issue), you could reuse `str` for the split - `str = str.split(',');` (assuming you don't need to use it again). Don't forget you may need to trim the white-space from `shift()` and `pop()` also.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're really getting a performance problem from the large array (don't [optimize prematurely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimisation)), you could use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to extract the single strings and [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)/[`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) to find their positions:

```
str.slice(0, str.indexOf(','))
```

and

```
str.slice(str.lastIndexOf(',')+1) // 1==','.length
```

Answer (score 9):

It's really not a waste of space, since JavaScript is barely taking up any memory on the computer. Unless the string is gigabytes long, I wouldn't worry about it. To get the first and last, just do this:

```
arr = str.split(',');
var first=arr.shift(); //or arr[0];
var last=arr.pop(); //or arr[arr.length-1];
```

Comment: Why mutate the array? It's likely less efficient than getting the first and last index.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a long string of ISO dates

Assuming these are all using timezone `Z`, year `>= 0` and are spaced and quoted the same way, you don't even have to search for `,` because they will be of the same length.

```
var first = str.slice(1, 25),
    last = str.slice(-25, -1);
```

Answer (score -1):

There is `jsperf` using `substr` / `substring` that is the most optimal way. See:

https://jsperf.com/slice-vs-substr-vs-substring-vs-split-vs-regexp